# How do I compute the Weighted average ROC Curve?

Tags: scikit-learn, metric, roc

So i have a multiclass problem and successfully computed the micro and macro average curves, how do I calculate the weighted value for each TPR and FPR?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as micro-average?

Comment: area under the curve when using weighted average gives a different result than when using micro average, plus, here they are calculating the 3 curves: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/machine-learning/how-to-understand-automated-ml#roc-curve

Comment: Ok, why not. Then I wonder how does one interpret the difference between the two AUC values, since the micro-average is already meant to take into account the proportion by class. In general I don't think that ROC curves are a good representation for the multiclass setting, and the AUC in particular is not clearly interpretable like it is in the binary setting.